# C API with Mysql in XCode

Tags: mysql, c, xcode, macos

Setup: Running Mac OSX Snow Leopard, X Code 3.2.1, Mysql 5.1.42 and Mysql C-Connector 6.0.2, all 64-bit.

I am having real difficulty configuring X-Code to run Mysql scripts. XCode is running fine (i.e. can Build and Run), MySQL server is running and I am confident on the installation of the programs listed under my Setup at the top of this post. The problem is when I Build & Run I get 2 different errors over the hours of trying: either mysql.h cannot be found (so all Mysql script commands fail) or I get a "dyld: Library not loaded: libmysql.16.dylib" when I configure it with the correct include file location. I ran mysql_config and the results were:

--include:
-I/usr/local/include

--libs:
-L/usr/local/lib -lmysql -lpthread

--cflags:
-I/usr/local/include

--libs_r:
-L/usr/local/lib -lmysql -lpthread

It seems to me that I am not configuring the Project Settings correctly in X Code, namely:
Search Paths - Header Search Paths 
Search Paths - Library Search Paths 
Linking - Other Linker Flags

I also followed advice on the following forum: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?117,51324,127220#msg-127220

Amongst many other things.

I would really value any advice - all coding has ceased until this error can be resolved!

Thank you in advance.

Oliver

Comment: I'm having the same trouble. Did you found any workaround for this?

Comment: my two cents for Catalina: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17465902/use-of-external-c-headers-in-objective-c/60130956#60130956

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the fix. This happens because the dylib files are not installed properly. In order to make the dylib files the proper way, do (supposing that we have our libraries on `usr/local/mysql/lib`):

```
sudo install_name_tool -id /usr/local/mysql/lib/NAMEOFTHELIB.dylib NAMEOFTHELIB.16.dylib
```

This will add in the absolute path, and will make the libraries work.