# Use of external C++ headers in Objective-C

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, xcode, include-path

In my iOS project I need to use an external library written in C++.  The C++ header files are all in one directory.

I've added these C++ headers to my Xcode project, and also specified a header search path (in  Build Settings).

The issue is that these C++ headers include each other using < > angle brackets.  This results in:

```
'filename.h' file not found with <angled> include, use "quotes" instead.
```

The weird thing is that Xcode does not complain about all headers.  Also the same header #include'd in one file is fine, while an issue when #include'd in another.  I think this is caused by the fact that these headers #include each other.

1. Why doesn't the search path work?
2. Is there a way to resolve this without modifying these header files?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have the sources and the Xcode project of that C++ library?

Comment: @CouchDeveloper No I don't.

Comment: Does setting the "Always Search User Paths" build setting help?

Comment: @MartinR Holy smokes, yes! :-)  Put it as answer and I will reward.  I've removed the `-I`, nice.  Why did `-I` not work?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
#include <bla.h>
```

is meant for standard library or framework headers, and the search strategy 
Is different than that used for

```
#include "bla.h"
```

See for example

- [What is the difference between #include <filename> and #include "filename"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/what-is-the-difference-between-include-filename-and-include-filename)

As a workaround, you can set the Xcode build setting "Always Search User Paths" to YES.

Comment: Note that setting "Always Search User Paths" to YES may cause header issues. It's strongly recommended to set it to NO, and that's the correct way. It's still only there for backward compatibilities. The third party library's headers should be included via angle brackets.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper: It was meant as a workaround, but you are right and your answer is problably the better solution.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper agree that the this setting should be set to NO, but is there anything undesirable setting this setting to YES in the context of building an embedded framework?

Answer (score 15):

Starting from a "blank" application project:

1. Create a folder "Libraries" in your application's project - preferable as a sibling to your MyApp.xcodeproj file, but it can be anywhere. Create subfolders for each Configuration (Debug, Release, etc.) and possibly for each architecture (armv7, armv7s, arm64) unless the binary is universal binary archive containing all architectures.
2. Get the headers of the third party library and the static library binaries (possibly more than one for different platforms, Configurations and architectures) and move them  into the "Library" folder into corresponding subfolders (which you may need to create):

   For example, assuming you had a universal binary (armv7, armv7s, arm64) and Debug and Release versions of that library:
   Now, the folder structure is assumed to be as follows:

   ```
   $(SRCROOT)/Libraries
       Debug-iphoneos
           include
               ThirdParty
                   third_party.hh 
                   ...
           libThirdParty.a             
       Release-iphoneos
           include
               ThirdParty
                   third_party.hh 
                   ...
           libThirdParty.a             
   MyApp.xcodeproj
   ```
3. "Library Search Paths" Build Setting:

   Drag the "Libraries" folder into your Xcode project. This *may* automatically create a library search path in the build settings. Please verify this, and if it is not correct, fix it.

   Given the example, add the following library search paths for Debug and Release Configuration:

   Debug:   **Library Search Paths**: `$(SRCROOT)/Libraries/Debug-iphoneos`

   Release: **Library Search Paths**: `$(SRCROOT)/Libraries/Release-iphoneos`

   You may have different library search paths for particular Configuration and Target platform pairs. Set different path's in the build setting accordingly.
4. "Header Search Paths" Build Setting:

   Given the example, add the following header search path to the Debug and the Release Configuration:

   Debug: **Header Search Paths**: `$(SRCROOT)/Libraries/Debug-iphoneos/include`

   Release: **Header Search Paths**: `$(SRCROOT)/Libraries/Release-iphoneos/include`

   Likewise, you may have different paths for particular Config/Target pairs - although the headers may be the same.
5. Link your app against the C++ standard library by adding `-lc++` to the **Other Linker Flags** build setting.
6. Import the header in your files as follows:

   ```
    #import <ThirdParty/third_party.hh>
   ```

Comment: That helped, since that error was target-dependent in my case.

Comment: Epic, first time I can make the angle includes work with a 3rd party library that I have in my project because I want to patch it. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

In Xcode 9, I need to add header files path to the `Header Search Paths` build setting, not `User Header Search Paths`.

Xcode will append `User Header Search Paths` to compile command as `-iquote` options, but append `Header Search Paths` as `-I` options. That's the key difference.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. (I had not time to check it though, I trust you.)

Answer (score 0):

In XCode after setting the "User Header Search Paths" to point to your library's directory, you also have to make sure that a field called "Always Search User Paths" is set to "Yes"

This solved the problem I was having: with <boost/signals2.hpp> file not found with <angled> include, use "quotes" instead.

Answer (score 0):

my two cents for OSX / Mysql.
(by the way I ask why that bogus use of <> in mysql... anyway..)

As per Xcode 11 warning, **"Disabling it is strongly recommended.",**

I prefer to patch another setting, leaving  "Always Search User Paths" to "No".

I set:

HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS = "/usr/local/mysql/include".

**LINKER:**

**I)** 
If You got link error, add "libmysqlclient.a" usually in "/usr/local/mysql/lib", simply dragging from Finder)

**II: You can get a worst error...**

"/usr/local/lib/libmysqlclient.21.dylib: code signature in (/usr/local/lib/libmysqlclient.21.dylib) not valid for use in process using Library Validation: mapping process and mapped file (non-platform) have different Team IDs"

As that lib is not signed. Simply in Entitlemens:

(in XML):
..

```
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.cs.disable-library-validation</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
...
```

[image]