# Error while including c++ files and folders into iOS xcode project

Tags: c++, ios

In my project I need to use an external files and folders which are written in C++ relates to OpenGL framework.

I've added these C++ headers to my Xcode project, and also specified a header search path (Build Settings -> Header search paths).
Everything works fine in demo project but getting error while adding to original project which has 2 projects with a single workspace.

```
Error :file not found with <angled> include; use "quotes" instead
```

Getting this error at the time of compilation.
If I tried with include statement with quotes again it is generating some more errors.

How to use external c++ libraries and headers in iOS objective-c project?
Unable to find the issue.It may be a duplicate question but I dint found a solution.
Need suggestions to resolve this error.

Comment: You should check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17465902/use-of-external-c-headers-in-objective-c

Comment: Tried all those solutions but issue not resolved

Answer (score 1):

Resolved issue.It was problem with folder structure and path.Added proper path in Header Search Paths in Build Settings.